# Error : Could not load file or assembly or one of it's dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

[image: error massage]

My current project name is "Power". I have been working on this project for weeks now, and it's almost over now. But today when I try to Debug, this error came.

> Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly 'Power' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I compared the project folder in Documents with another project folder but nothing seemed to be missing. (ex: *.cs , *.resx , *.config ,  *.manifest) I didn't delete anything from the project folder.

- Visual Studio 2010
- C#.net
- .NETFRAMEWORK 4.0

Please help me to solve this.
ThankYou!

Comment: **Build -> Clean Solution** than **Build -> Rebuild** it will fix your issue

Comment: @Mohit Shrivastava : Nope. Error is still there.

Comment: Check the list of Dll's in the output folder. Make sure all needed dll's are present. Try to check the properties of 3rd party or non .NET framework assembly to have the "Copy Local" set to "True".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah...!!! I found a solution for this terrible error...
First of all Thanks for every one who tried to help me... Here's my solution...

> 1. Right Click on the Solution name
> 2. Click Clean Solution
> 3. Restart Visual Studio
> 4. Goto project Properties >> Build
> 5. Change **Configuration** to **Release**
> 6. Start Debugging (F5)

**1) , 2)**

[image: Right Click on the Solution name]

**4) , 5)**

[image: Change Configuration to Release]

Next time keep in mind to keep a recent backup of your project folder.

Comment: thank's for the solution . it really works +10 for you.

Answer (score 2):

Solving build errors is pretty much impossible without having direct access to your projects or solution. But I'll try and give you some guidance to find the root of your problem.

According to the error message you're receiving, the of the build-error is being caused by a project called "Power".
Look in the `References` of that project and see if any are missing or corrupt. You can tell if there is a yellow exclamation-mark next to it. Simply remove that reference and add it again.

Comment: `References` are ok, there are no yellow marks. As the error say _The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest._ Neither this project nor other projects have a file named **assembly manifest**. But my earlier projects are working well.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following

> > Remove Temporary Files
> >     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
> >             Close Visual studio   and Open Again

0r

> **Remove and Add the same DLLs (Note: you add the same matching versions)**

Comment: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
Folder is empty.

Comment: You mean I have to replace all `*.dll` files in the _C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319_ folder?

Comment: Remove  the referenced dll and Add it again

Comment: is it  web  application?

Comment: it might be set to 32-bit while the class its referencing is set to 64-bit

Comment: it worked well yesterday. I didn't change the settings today.

Comment: I just now tried with the 64-bit but the same error occured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89943/discussion-between-midhun-mundayadan-and-roshana-pitigala).

Answer (score 0):

This methods worked for me:
1. Removed bin folder
2. Rebuilt the solution
3. Run a project